# Windows Azure - RPC Server is unavailable error

Tags: asp.net, windows, azure, cloud

We are working on the Windows Azure platform. The application is working fine if we work from Visual Studio but when we deploy it to Windows Azure and tried to Run from the URL created its throwing RPC Server Unavailable. If Anyone of you people facing the same issues kindly helps us in resolving the same.

**http://sharum1016854.cloudapp.net/WelcomePage.aspx** --> Please click on any button then the following error is throwing.

**the error we are getting is:**

> The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA) 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The
>   RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [COMException (0x800706ba): The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)]
>   LastTest.WelcomePage.btnCreate_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   D:\AzureApplication\LastTest\WelcomePage.aspx.cs:35
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +154    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +3707

Please give some suggestions regarding the same as soon as possible...

Comment: What sort of remote calls are you making, the error code has to do with com+/dcom? For example, do you make a connection azure reporting?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason is that your code uses an out-proc COM server that you deploy on the same machine during role startup. Later you instantiate an object in that server and COM subsystem provides you with a proxy object. The communication between your code and the COM server is done using RPC - an RPC server is started inside the out-proc COM server. Then the COM server crashes and all you have is a proxy to a now non-existing COM server (and non-existing RPC server). When you perform any call on the dangling proxy you face this error message - *RPC server is unavailable*.

You have to find what COM server crashes and why it does so and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure where the issue is encountered. But according to http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4494.troubleshooting-the-rpc-server-is-unavailable.aspx, the issue can occur if a computer name cannot be found. I would like to know whether you are using computer name in your code. By default, a Windows Azure machine is not in your local network, so you cannot connect to a local machine using machine name. If you want to invoke an on-premises service, you can use Windows Azure Connect.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: ya we are using computer name in our code and we uased windows azure connect also but still got the same error.

Comment: You cannot use compute name in Windows Azure. Windows Azure is not in the local domain (unless you use Connect to join the local domain). If you want to communicate between two instances, please use internal endpoint rather than machine name.

Comment: yes later i came to know that we can not use machine name so tried with internal endpoint. but the windows azure connect is not activating... what might be the problem? is that anything related to firewall ports?